# Why a[v] = v[a]?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

v it's an array of ints and a it's an int:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int v[10], a;
cout << v[a] << endl;
cout << a[v] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

returns the same value:
0
0

Why is that ?

Comment: Because they're both translated to `*(a+v)`.

Comment: There is no declaration for `a` here.

Comment: sorry John Dibling, I edited now.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question which already has been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the indexer syntax means "the value in the address denoted by *the beginning of the array plus an offset*". Or, to put it another way:

```
v[a] == *(v + a) == *(a + v) == a[v]
```